# Do incoming and outgoing ports have to match?

Tags: ssh, port, sftp

Our server was setup with sftp on a custom port, say, `12345`. The connection could be done like so, and required the port setting:

```
sftp -oPort 12345 user@host
```

I understand that is at least specifying the server's port. Does it also fix the client's port? For example, if a client is behind a firewall that has port restrictions, could it use another port to make the connection?

I believe [this serverfault answer](https://serverfault.com/a/179172/154318) answers the question but I would like to confirm. This explicit question may also make it easier for people to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The client port number is independent of server running on port 12345. Usually the client when uses `connect` to any server, the system assigns a random port number for connection on its side. You need not worry about client side port numbers. They will have to configure their IP tables to be able to reach you.

If any rule in IP tables on client side that says to stop any out bound connections destined with port number 12345 will cause host unreachable. If that's what you are worried about.

Comment: I think I see. A system can be configured for incoming, outgoing and destination ports, all independently. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, study IP tables. You will get a clear picture.